# AWS ALB OIDC authentication cookie domain issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a AWS Cloudfront hosted webpage which takes static pages from S3 and makes calls to custom origin (ALB) for dynamic data. There is OIDC authentication enabled on ALB, so calls to custom origin (my API) passes via rules set at ALB.

In a particular case when my request to custom origin is unauthenticated I am redirected to IdP for login and after successful login I get the cookie in the response header, as this request was sent to IdP from ALB - the issued cookie has domain as ALB DNS. In order for my webpage to use this cookie I have to redirect the call to Cloudfront URL. Now the cookie was issued to ALB which has a different DNS and my Cloudfront URL has a different DNS  therefore I am unable to use the cookie.

I tried to catch the cookie value but because it is issued for a different domain i am unable to catch hold, also as a part of design I feel that is wrong. Has some one faced similar type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

AWS ALB OIDC sets session cookie for the same request host domain for which you configure the authentication action in the listener rules.

Also, they set a http only secure cookie, meaning you cannot access it via client side Javascript at all.

Considering this along with your setup, it seems you actually need a (tiny) backend for your web page, so that you can access the response cookie when you make the API call to the mentioned custom origin internally from this backend.

Comment: Except this does not work. The ALB filters the auth cookie. Rename it and you get to see it but this is just to test the case. HttpOnly prevents this from working in code